SignalR connection.start().then() doesn't work as expected
Let's say in my reactJS client, I created a signalr hubconnection like this:
function App() {
  const [connection, setConnection] = useState();

  const createConn = async (navigateFunc) => {
    const conn = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl('https://localhost:7028/chat')
      .configureLogging(LogLevel.Information)
      .build();
    await conn.start().then(function () {
      setConnection(conn);
      if (connection == null) console.log("connection is null")
    })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Login createConn={createConn}/>}></Route>
      </Routes>

    </div>
  );
}

My Login.js component (I shortened it):
const Login = ({ createConn }) => {
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        createConn();
return (
            <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className='mt-5'>
                <Form.Group>
                    <Form.Control placeholder='Email...' type='text' className='d-flex p-2' onChange={changeHanler} />
                    <Button variant='success' type='submit' >Join</Button>
                </Form.Group>
            </Form>
        </div>
    )
}

I got "connection is null" as the result.
So clearly something is wrong here. function inside then() will be called when the promise is fulfilled, so the connection must have been established and then setConnection() got called, but as you can see my state connection is null. And no exception was logged.
So what is going on? Or maybe because my understanding of Promise is incorrect? If it is, can somebody please correct me?

When is  the const [connection, setConnection] = useState(); code executed? It takes a copy of the connection value when executed,, and if null or undefined at that time and not updated since, will still be falsey when tested in then supplied handler function posted.

I have updated my question. As you can see the line of code you mentioned is executed in App.js. Then inside createConn() after conn.start(), I will call setConnection(conn). This function is called inside Login component. Could you check it out?

OK, so connection  is copied first - try logging it immediately after setting it. If its null at that stage it will still be when tested later - it needs to be updated after starting the connection to be of use. I know nothing about APC.Net and little about React so would suggest checking if setConnection returns anything useful for checking its success, or takes additional parameters for callback functions to handle errors. You could try retrieving the value of connection again but I don't know if that's the recommended way of doing it.

Since start returns a promise, errors should cause the promise to be rejected. If you can confirm that, then you don't need the connection test anyway - although you may need the actual value of connection.

Have you checked connecting to the SignalR server from other clients? Can you post the ASP.NET SignalR server code?

Immediately after setConnection(conn) is executed, then connection is still the old value.
The execution of setConnection(conn) doesn't change connection immediately, but merely "schedules" the update of connection for the next render. setConnection(conn) also will cause the component to be re-rendered, i.e. the function App() is executed again, but only after all other "immediate" js code has finished its execution.
So inside the then block, connection is still the old value, and when the App() is executed the next time, const [ connection, ... is called again, which is (of course) a new and separate variable (which should have the expected value, but too late for your then block).
So maybe your connection variable just works as expected, but only not yet inside the then block (That depends on how you use connection in the end, which is not part of the question).
React works more "declarative" and less "imperative", i.e. you should basically never expect that "B happens after A", but understand the guarantees that React makes, and declare the dependencies between different states.
